# Esp32 rf design review

Tags: pcb, rf, radio, wifi, esp32

Preamble: this is the first time I'm working in rf circuit design, I went simple and I hope I didn't make any silly mistakes, but I still have some doubts.

I am currently designing a garden programmer based on the [esp32-s3](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s3_datasheet_en.pdf).

To handle the rf input (LNA_IN) I have used a filter ([2450FM07D0034T](https://www.johansontechnology.com/datasheets/2450FM07D0034/2450FM07D0034.pdf)) and an antenna ([P/N 2450AT18B100](https://www.johansontechnology.com/datasheets/2450AT18B100/2450AT18B100.pdf)) as shown in chunk of schematic below:
[image]

My doubts are as follows:

- The filter 2450FM07D0034T specifies an INPUT and an OUTPUT, since the esp transmits and receives, is this filter still suitable for this application or do I need another type?
- There is a relay on the board that handles 220VAC, would this give problems to the rf communication? Would it be better to have it routed to the bottom plane?
- Also, how does the rf design look on the pcb? (the rf line was matched using the [manufacturer's calculator](https://cart.jlcpcb.com/impedanceCalculation) (Order selection:JLC2313) and the stackup is SIG-GND-3V3-SIG)

[image]

old schematic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFhd0.png

updated schematic: ( updated following Kartman's suggestions )
[image]
full pcb:

[image]

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you all very much.

Comment: There’s a numbet of issues, but the most safety critical one is your relay. You have nowhere near the required clearance between the 240V wiring and your ground plane. I would also suggest a different relay that has more clearance as well. No diode across thexrelay coil. Vias in the smt pads ( only a issue if you get the board asembled and put through an oven). Capacitors on the regulator, no overvoltage protection on the input. The RF layout looks suspect.

Comment: Right, I totally forgot about the flyback diode, also the clearance is a good point that I missed. Over voltage protection is not a "wanted feature" because I will power it from a 12V battery. What do You mean about Capacitors on the regulator? And what about the RF design? What do You mean with suspect? Thank you.

Comment: If you have a length of wire between the battery and the unit, you probably want over voltage protection due to lightning. What is the fuse there for? You have a 100uF cap on the output of the reg. Will the reg like this? Check datasheet. The value and choice of the caps looks haphazard. More guess than design. When I say suspect it means that at a brief glance it does not look correct yo my eyes. Evidence of calculations are needed. You have 4 layers but the top gnd fill is not ‘nailed’ to the gnd plane with vias. There’s a lot you havent told us so we can only guess.

Comment: Please append the updated designs to the question, instead of rewriting the question and replacing all images. Whoever comes here is now confused by the discussion as they do no longer relate to your question.